# WebGrid com RadioButton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radiobutton, webgrid

Quero selecionar uma linha do *WebGrid* através de um *RadioButton* e, ao clicar no botão *Visualizar*, carregar uma *partial view* com as informações da linha selecionada.

Como devo fazer para passar as informações da linha selecionada para o `controller`?

CSHTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppEight.Models.ContratosUnidade>
<link href="~/Content/Perfil/webgrid-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Perfil/perfil-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 6);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ContratoSelecionado", "Contratos", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",

        fillEmptyRows: true,
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        columns: new[]
        {
            grid.Column(format:@<text><input type="radio" 
                                 id="contratosUnidade" 
                                 name="contratosUnidade" 
                                 checked="@item.Codigo" /></text>, 
                                 style: "webgrid-select-column"),
            grid.Column("Codigo", "Código"),
            grid.Column("FormaContratacao", "Forma de Contratação")
       }
   )

<div class="ddldiv">
    <input class="input-buttons-footer" type="submit" value="Visualizar" />
    <input class="input-buttons-footer" type="submit" value="Editar" />
    <input class="input-buttons-footer" type="submit" value="Novo" />
    <input class="input-buttons-footer" type="submit" value="<" />
</div>
```

}

Controller(que deveria receber alguma informação da linha selecionada):

```
  public ActionResult ContratoSelecionado(string codigo)
  {
      return View();
  }
```

**Obs:** O controller `ContratoSelecionado` é chamado, no entanto, sem parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

para visualizar ao clicar no check-box, você também pode usar o trecho abaixo:

```
    grid.Column(header: "Visualizar?", format: @<text><input class="check-box" id="assignChkBx" name="assignChkBx" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" /></text>),
```

E no javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#assignChkBx").click(function () {
        var id = $('#assignChkBx').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ContratoSelecionado',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: id,
        success: function (data) {
        //alert('sucesso!!');
      },
        error: function (error) {
        //loading(0, "");
      }
    });
   });
});
```